# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined but it is defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```js
for(let i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
        let ref_num = row[i].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].innerText;
        row[i].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].innerHTML = "<button onclick=generateProcessLogQuery(this.value)>"+ref_num+"</button>"
        console.log("Ref Number : ",ref_num);
}

function generateProcessLogQuery(refresh){
        console.log("Hrere : ",refresh)
}
```

I am getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: generateProcessLogQuery is not defined

but you can see that it is defined.

Comment: Is it defined on the window object, or in a more confined scope?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if JS says the function is not defined, then it is not defined ...

Comment: Hi Teemu, I have posted the code it is defined as you can see.

Comment: @Hearner — How would that cause generateProcessLogQuery to be defined?

Comment: Sorry mbadeveloper & Hearner your answer is not working

Comment: @Quentin he updated his question after i answered

Comment: @Hearner — I can see the edit history. The only changes were for formatting.

Answer (score 4):

While it is defined in the fragment of code you have shown us, it isn't defined in the scope that the `onclick` function eventually runs in.

Don't generate JS nested in HTML by mashing strings together.

Use DOM. This lets you keep references and scope.

```
let button = document.createElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    generateProcessLogQuery(this.value);
});
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ref_num);
row[i].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].appendChild(button);
```

NB: It is odd to use `this.value` on a button you are defining without a value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar; in my case I had the function defined inside a document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// function was here and should not have been to call from HTML
});
```